# How can I solve this error sending notifications using FCM?

Tags: node.js, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I'm using FCM to send notifications to some devices(Android and iOS), but I've been getting these errors lately. For some reason the code was working at some point but now I'm getting errors again.

That's the body of my message:

```
let message = {
  apns:{
    payload: {
      aps: {
        alert:{
          title: "Title",
          body: "Body"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  token: device.fcmToken
};
```

And this is the code I'm using to send the messages(Admin send messages examples):

```
admin.messaging().send(message)
.then((response) => {
  console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log('Error sending message:', error);
});
```

The tokens are valid because I used the console and the messages went through
[image]

And these are the errors:

```
errorInfo: 
   { code: 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered',
     message: 'Requested entity was not found.' },
  codePrefix: 'messaging' }
errorInfo: 
   { code: 'messaging/invalid-payload',
     message: 'Messaging payload contains an invalid "topic" property. Valid properties are "data" and "notification".' },
  codePrefix: 'messaging' }
errorInfo: 
   { code: 'messaging/invalid-argument',
     message: 'Request contains an invalid argument.' },
  codePrefix: 'messaging' }
errorInfo: 
   { code: 'messaging/invalid-apns-credentials',
     message: 'Invalid APNS credential' },
  codePrefix: 'messaging' }
errorInfo: 
   { code: 'messaging/invalid-argument',
     message: 'The registration token is not a valid FCM registration token' },
  codePrefix: 'messaging' }
errorInfo: 
   { code: 'messaging/invalid-argument',
     message: 'Value of [aps] must be a non-empty dictionary.' },
  codePrefix: 'messaging' }
errorInfo: 
   { code: 'messaging/invalid-argument',
     message: 'Payload of Apple Push Notification Service must contain an [aps] key.' },
  codePrefix: 'messaging' }
errorInfo: 
   { code: 'messaging/mismatched-credential',
     message: 'Firebase Cloud Messaging API has not been used in project 158024523272 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/fcm.googleapis.com/overview?project=158024523272 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.' },
  codePrefix: 'messaging' }
```

Before that chain of errors I was receiving this message:

```
Successfully sent message: projects/project-ID/messages/8472962925969988574
```

What am I doing wrong? And how can I fix it? to get the successfully sent message again :(

Thank you guys for any help.

Comment: Have you managed to resolve this?

Comment: Well, I just decided to use another library to connect to APNS. With FCM it was saying message was successfully sent but nothing ever happened after that.